# How do I use a parameter in a query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, variables, select, parameters

Error: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: codigo

Here is the code:

```
System.out.println("Codigo del curso que quiere consultar las matriculas");
codigo = intSc.nextInt();
Cursos curso = (Cursos) session.get(Matricula.class, codigo);
Query query1 = session.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Matricula m where m.codigo=codigo");
List<Matricula> matriculas = query1.list();
for (Matricula matricula : matriculas) {
     System.out.println(matricula.toString());
}
```

I think the problem its im trying to insert a parameter on a select sentence, anyone know who i can insert it ?

Really thanks for the help :D

Structure of Matricula

@Entity

@Table(name = "Matricula")
public class Matricula implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "num_matricula", unique=true)
private int num_matricula;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="codigo_curso")
private Cursos curso;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="codigo_alumno")
private Alumnos alumno;
```

The new error is: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: codigo of: Proyecto.Matricula

Thanks for fast answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use syntax like this

```
    Query query1 = session.createQuery("FROM Matricula where curso=:curso");
    query1.setEntity("curso", curso);
```

if what you want to achieve is selecting Matricula which have that particular curso.

Comment: I'm getting new error with this :(                             org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: codigo of: Proyecto.Matricula

Comment: with the information you have provided I cannot help much. What is the structure of Matricula table? What is the new error?

Comment: see my updated answer. If it does not work, let me please know what is the structure of the Matricula table.

Comment: I updated the main post with the structure of matricula, really thanks :D

Comment: have a look now if this solves what you want. If not, tell me what you want to achieve, in fact you should have told that since the beginning :)

Comment: What i want its to insert with keyboard a "curso" like 2 , 3 or another one. The query must find on "matriculas" and show me what "matriculas" has on the row "curso" the "curso" im finding. With the last edit i get a new error. entity for parameter binding cannot be null

Comment: I see, here is the problem: `Cursos curso = (Cursos) session.get(Matricula.class, codigo);` should be `Cursos curso = (Cursos) session.get(Cursos.class, codigo);`. Ensure that there is a row with id that has value of `codigo`.